# Отобразить simple html в UILabel

Tags: cocoa, objective-c

Добрый день, пишу приложение, оно получает с сервера текст с тегами `<b>` и `<a>` нужно корректно отобразить эти куски текста в `UILable` или в `UITextView` на крайний случай. Хотелось бы получить простое решение без использования сторонних фреймворков с километрами кода.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если действительно есть строгое ограничение на не-использование сторонних фреймворков, то ответ: регулярные выражения + `NSMutableAttributedString`, если нет - то может быть https://github.com/mattt/TTTAttributedLabel подойдёт для Ваших целей?